# How to compare two arrays and return a difference in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am building an app using ReactJS library and trying to figure out how to return a difference after comparing two arrays.

```
const a = [8,10,13,14];
const b = [{id: 8}, {id: 13}, {id: 14}];
```

and what I would like to get is 
`[10]`.

What I have tried and didn't work was using map and filter together.

```
const newArray = b.map((itemB) => {
    return a.filter(
       itemA => itemB.id !== itemA,
    );
});
```

What is the simple way of returning this?

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you tried. Numerous ways you can acheive this. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective is to help you with your code

Comment: Yup, edited the question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the difference between two arrays in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/how-to-get-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @minus.273 Thanks for the comment, but I wanted to sort out when there are the object keys in an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just filter the unwanted id?

```js
const a = [8, 10, 13, 14];
const b = [{ id: 8 }, { id: 13 }, { id: 14 }];

console.log(a.filter(num => !b.some(({ id }) => id === num)));
```

Answer (score 2):

As you have two array with different item-types, you could combine `Array.filter()` with `Array.map()` to get the difference:

```js
const a = [8,10,13,14];
const b = [{id: 8}, {id: 13}, {id: 14}];

const normalized = b.map(({ id }) => id);
const diff = a.filter(value => !normalized.includes(value));

console.log(diff);
```

EDIT: I think @Brian Le's solution with `.some()` is more elegant (and probably more performant)!

Comment: Lots more efficient doing the map once only,  outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can use lodash.

```
const diff = _.difference(a, b.map(({ id }) => id));
```